# How to join the two columns that are in separate tables in the third table

Tags: sql-server

Please help in solving the following query,

```
(
 f.CURS_AMT, c.C_NAME, s.SID FROM COURSE_FEE_DTL f 
 JOIN COURSE_MASTER c ON f.C_CODE = c.C_CODE
 JOIN STUDEDNT_MASTER s ON s. C_NAME = c.C_NAME                      
  )
```

When the sp is executed error arises as 'too many arguments specified'

Comment: This looks like a fragment of a query. Could you post the whole query.

Comment: If you cut and pasted that, there's a typo as well:
STUDEDNT_MASTER should probably be STUDENT_MASTER

Answer (score 1):

I would guess this is really the full query you need;

```
  SELECT f.CURS_AMT, c.C_NAME, s.SID 
  FROM COURSE_FEE_DTL f 
  JOIN COURSE_MASTER c ON f.C_CODE = c.C_CODE
  JOIN STUDENT_MASTER s ON s.C_NAME = c.C_NAME
```

There was no SELECT to begin the query, the mistype @nickd pointed out and a space in the join syntax for the second join.